# Accidentally trashed large file

Tags: shell-script, debian, file-copy, ntfs, deleted-files

I accidentally moved an entire directory of ***~100GB*** to trash. I was trying to place it in bookmarks but dragged it into trash. It's there in the trash. But

> **when i try to restore I run out of space on the disk**

Prior to deletion I had less than 50GB free on disk, if I need to restore the normal way I need about 68GB more free on the disk. That is

> **if I have to restore I have to delete every file from trash
>   immediately after restoring it**

so i can revert back to initial state. I tried to use `"rsync -av --remove-source-files /Trash/file /Dest"`
but it also doesn't work.
Any suggestions to solve the problem ?
*I use MX17 beta 2 based on debian stable.The disk is NTFS formatted.*

Comment: What does "not work" with your attempt with `rsync`?

Comment: @Kusalananda The same error "No space left on device", On trying with file manager "Error splicing: No more space"

Comment: Could you move the files one by one, either manually or, if there are too many of them, with a simple loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are moving to the same partition then

```
mv /source/* /dest/
```

should work [without creating a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998036/how-does-linuxs-mv-work-internally#28998092) or consuming more space

Alternatively, just do the same exercise with `/dest/` on an external drive or partition then copy them back once you have cleared space in your original location.

Comment: Unfortunately this is my only large partition and i dont have external disks... I'll try to use mv again thank you for pointing me to internal working of mv and i'll let you know the progress.